# How can I diagnose my MacBook Pro Start-up problem?

Tags: macbook-pro, install, memory

[image]I have a MacBook Pro 8,1 (Early 2011) / 8GB (2x4GB RAM) /256 SSD  and was running El Captain. One morning I couldn't boot it up.

After doing the Apple Hardware Test which showed faulty RAM I put back my old 4GB (2x2GB) RAM sticks, retested and had no errors. I had all my data on an external drive so I did a complete restore back to Lion 10.7.5. After installing the system, the Spinning wheel of death appears very frequently, but I put that down the indexing which had a remaining time of 5 days. After rebooting the system once, I couldn't boot it again.

I have done the hardware test multiple times since then and everything checks out fine. I have installed Lion twice since then also, but if I do a restart it never boots further than the grey Apple logo and spinning wheel  like the very first time. I have tried all start-up options. Safe-mode never boots. At the moment I am trying the "Choose Startup Disk" option and choose the partition but I only see the wheel of death.

After doing a verbose boot, the system did infact reboot after approximately 3 hours. However, even just entering my login password brings back the spinning wheel of death which runs for a couple of minutes so that the mac is effectively useless and then "kernel panic".

How can I diagnose what is going on here? Processor, Permissions? Other problems?

Comment: Several questions here...do you have 16GB of RAM or 8GB?  Your old sticks, do you have 2GB or 4GB?   Your use of the 2x/4x is incorrect. Next, if you detect a RAM error, what prompted you to reinstall macOS?    If you couldn't boot up, as you say in the second sentence, how did you run Disk Utility as you say in your third?

Comment: (UPDATE: Verbose mode triggers a kernel panic "panic cpu 0 caller 0xfff...et c)

Comment: Sorry...I updated the question to include the answers

Comment: I had 2 x 4GB sticks. Then the crash! - Then (due to the fact that I wasn´t experienced enough) without first doing the Hardware test, I tried a restore. Only after having absolutely no success downloading over WLAN did I try the hardware test out of sheer desparation and realised the RAM Error. After reverting back to 2 x 2GB ram sticks and verifying that the hardware had no more problems, I managed to install Lion 10.7.5- but now it doesn´t boot.

Comment: You did that backward.  AHT is your first procedure; reinstall is what you do out of desperation.  This is like checking for a heart attack *after* you've done the heart transplant because you felt a pain in your chest which turned out to be indigestion.  That said, how are you installing Lion?  Do you have a USB installer?  If not, can you get access to a Mac to make one?

Comment: I installed Lion by doing an internet restore over WLAN. I don´t know anyone else with a mac.

Comment: After 3 hours, the login screen has arrived

Comment: Download the upgrade to El Capitan or High Sierra, make a [bootable USB installer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254342/119271) and install that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73139/discussion-between-robert-buckley-and-allan).

Answer (score 1):

Solution to my problem was to buy a new internal Sata 
cable. I could have spared myself a whole lot of trouble if I had done that at the start.